# Get list of all USB Mass Storage devices

Tags: macos, iokit

So I have a USB Mass Storage device, which exposes two disks to the macOS. 
I get detect the first one using https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412808/rafael-baptista 's article: 
https://oroboro.com/usb-serial-number-osx/

However, I cannot get the second one using code:

```
io_registry_entry_t    child;
io_iterator_t        child_iterator    = MACH_PORT_NULL;
kern_return_t        kr;

kr = IORegistryEntryCreateIterator(usbDevice,
                                   kIOServicePlane,
                                   kIORegistryIterateRecursively,
                                   &child_iterator);
if (kr != kIOReturnSuccess) {
    return;
}

while ((child = IOIteratorNext(child_iterator)) != MACH_PORT_NULL) {
    CFStringRef bsdName = NULL;

    bsdName = ( CFStringRef ) IORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty(child, kIOServicePlane, CFSTR( kIOBSDNameKey ), kCFAllocatorDefault, kIORegistryIterateRecursively );

    if ( bsdName ) {
....
```

I'd appreciate any pointers or information of what I could have done better here.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your `usbDevice` handle coming from? Surely, that's the key to this problem.

Comment: It comes from     usbDevice = IOIteratorNext( iterator ) , the iterator you get when new matching devices are detected. I don't think its an issue.

Comment: Well, are you iterating over multiple usbDevices then? Does that part work?

Comment: yes, it does :-)

Comment: OK, so where exactly is it going wrong on the second device? You're getting an io_service_t handle to the second device, but it can't find the BSDName property on it? Have you checked that the device is represented in the IOKit registry in the way you expect using `ioreg` or IORegistryExplorer? Maybe show us the ioreg output subtree for the device where it works and the one where it doesn't?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually two USB mass storage devices, and not two partitions on a single device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. Btw, I found a solution to this. I'm using disk arbitration to discover new drives.

```
  CFDictionaryRef dict = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);

    NSDictionary *diskDictionary = (__bridge NSDictionary *)dict;
    NSURL *mountPointURL = diskDictionary[(__bridge NSString *)kDADiskDescriptionVolumePathKey];
    NSString *deviceMountPath = [mountPointURL path];

    NSString *deviceDiskPath = diskDictionary[(__bridge NSString *)kDADiskDescriptionDevicePathKey];
```

deviceDiskPath will include IOPath, which will include device ID (or name) and VendorID !